# Excel Rows (1st column) as .php files + Excel Row 1 (2nd column to infinty) as data of all files

Tags: vba, excel

I found relevent things but not the exact match and I don't know how fix them.

I have an excel file with only 1 row(with many columns) and 1 column (with many rows).

Now I would like to use vba and create files from all the rows of 1st column and , put the same data (i.e. cloumn b to infinty of 1st row) inside all the files.

Just an example:

excel file:

```
a 2 3 4
b
c
```

files would be:

```
a.php, b.php, c.php
```

with same data inside them:

```
2 3 4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to use a `php` extension for a file of data? A `php` extension is generally used for program scripts written in the PHP programming language

Comment: 1st because I want to create php files so that I can upload them on web. 2nd column 'b' of 1st row will contain a specific php code @MarkBaker

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of writing PHP files as straight text files using a text editor rather than using MS Excel as an IDE of choice?

Comment: The idea of having three different files, all with the same content also eludes me

Comment: I have 200,000+ rows in excel, and I need to create files with them(so I believe VBA+Excel is a better approach), on web I am using/linking a db, so even with same content will get different datas/values on each php page @MarkBaker

Comment: This really does strike me as the most inefficient method of writing PHP that I have ever come across.... and your explanation still suggests that all files will be identical

Comment: So you want 200,000 identical files?  Surely this is a design issue.

Comment: let me do it, then I'll surely show you and discuss @MarkBaker

Comment: We're not stopping you doing it, especially as you've been given an answer.... we're just trying to understand the rationale behind what you want to do, which you're singularly failing to explain

Answer (score 0):

While the rationale for doing this to generate web content eludes me, this is trivial to do.  Just loop through the 1st row to get the data, then loop through the first column to get the filenames and output copies:

```
Const path = "C:\YourDestinationDirectory\"

Public Sub DumpPHP()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim data As String
    Dim index As Long

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet

    For index = 2 To sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        data = data & sheet.Cells(1, index)
    Next index

    Dim handle As Integer
    For index = 2 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        handle = FreeFile
        Open path & sheet.Cells(index, 1) & ".php" For Output As #handle
        Print #handle, data
        Close #handle
    Next index

End Sub
```